# Maximin diameter of a transformed convex figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

You are given a compact convex figure in the plane, $C$.

Your goal is to transform $C$ to a different figure $C'$ with the smallest possible diameter, as long as:

- The trasformation from $C$ to $C'$ is [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) and invertible (e.g. scaling in one or more directions);
- $C'$ contains a disc with diameter $1$.

For example:

- If $C$ is an ellipse, you can transform it to a disc with diameter $1$.
- If $C$ is a parallelogram, you can transform it to a square with side-length $1$ and diameter $\sqrt{2}$.
- If $C$ is a triangle, you can transform it to an equilateral triangle with diameter $\sqrt{3}$.

An ellipse is obviously the best case; what is the worst case?

Comment: Related: [Is there an simple algorithm for calculating maximum inscribed circle into a convex polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953623/is-there-an-simple-algorithm-for-calculating-maximum-inscribed-circle-into-a-conv).